# Error when altering field that is party of primary key, only on one server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two MSSQL Servers, one is SQL Server 2016, the other is SQL Server 2017.

On the SQL Server 2016, when I run this code:

```
ALTER TABLE [FSFIELDLABEL] ALTER COLUMN [VALIDATION_CODE] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;
```

Then I get the expected error:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The object 'FS_FIELDLABEL_PK' is dependent on column 'VALIDATION_CODE'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 3
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN VALIDATION_CODE failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

However, when I run that same command on SQL Server 2017, I don't get an error.  I've checked, and the same primary key exists on both databases, the one on the 2016 server, and the one on the 2017 server.

What user permissions or database settings can I look at to try and determine why these two servers behave differently?  The 2017 server is what our developers test against, so it really screws us up when they test code that "works" on the 2017 server, but then fails on the 2016 Server.

The SQL Create for the 2017 "no error" table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FSFIELDLABEL](
 [LANGUAGE_CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[VALIDATION_CODE] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[DATA_NAME] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[RECFMT_CODE] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
[LINE_ID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[LABEL] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[FORMAT_CODE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[VERSION] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[FS_SYS_ROWID] [int] NULL,
[TOOLTIP] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
[DISPLAY_TOOLTIP] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [FS_FIELDLABEL_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[LANGUAGE_CODE] ASC,
[VALIDATION_CODE] ASC,
[DATA_NAME] ASC,
[RECFMT_CODE] ASC,
[LINE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FSFIELDLABEL] ADD  DEFAULT ('A') FOR [RECFMT_CODE]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FSFIELDLABEL] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LINE_ID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FSFIELDLABEL] ADD  DEFAULT (' ') FOR [LABEL]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FSFIELDLABEL] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [DISPLAY_TOOLTIP]
GO
```

The SQL Create for the 2016 "non-working" server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FSFIELDLABEL](
[LANGUAGE_CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[VALIDATION_CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[DATA_NAME] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[RECFMT_CODE] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__FSFIELDLA__RECFM__63F8CA06]  DEFAULT ('A'),
[LINE_ID] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__FSFIELDLA__LINE___64ECEE3F]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[LABEL] [nvarchar](500) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__FSFIELDLA__LABEL__65E11278]  DEFAULT (' '),
[FORMAT_CODE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[VERSION] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[FS_SYS_ROWID] [int] NULL,
[TOOLTIP] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
[DISPLAY_TOOLTIP] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__FSFIELDLA__DISPL__2DA7A64D]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [FS_FIELDLABEL_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[LANGUAGE_CODE] ASC,
[VALIDATION_CODE] ASC,
[DATA_NAME] ASC,
[RECFMT_CODE] ASC,
[LINE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: The docs seem to suggest it shouldn't work on SQL Server 2017 either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments. Could you please post the full CREATE TABLE script for the table on each server?

Comment: added the requested Create Table scripts to the original question.

Comment: Thank you for posting that, I can't see any issue with the schema there. Is there any difference in the data stored in the tables between the 2016 and 2017 servers?

Comment: the data is not identical between the two tables, but it's pretty similar.  3599 rows in the working table, and 4050 rows in the non-working table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your column has a value in your SQL server 2016. On the other hand, in SQL 2017 your column does not have a value.

You can remove  `FS_FIELDLABEL_PK` and change your data type, and add again your constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare the following pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I found that they are identical.

I would suggest you to get the list of all objects (especially views) that are referring to the column VALIDATION_CODE and whether there is an object with schema binding in the server 2016 but not 2017.

With SQL Search or similar tools it should be very easy to get the list.

https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

***Edited:***

This is very interesting question, I tried to reproduce the issue on SQL Server 2016, and I found that I can reproduce this issue, but only when the new size of altered column is smaller than the current size ( nvarchar(30) to nvarchar(29) for example), keeping same size or increasing the size will **NOT** produce this issue, there is no impact whether the table is empty or not.

I believe this is the corresponding explanation for this issue, according to the [offcial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> ALTER COLUMN
>
> The modified column can't be:
>
> Used in statistics generated by the CREATE STATISTICS statement.
>   Unless the column is a varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary data type, the
>   data type isn't changed. And, the **new size is equal to or greater** than
>   the old size. Or, if the column is changed from not null to null.
>   First, remove the statistics using the DROP STATISTICS statement.

So the issue is due to the STATISTICS that is automatically added with the Primary Key.

I would suggest to drop the Primary key before ALTER statement and add it back thereafter.

Comment: sadly, we are altering an Nvarchar(20) to Nvarchar(30).  If we reduce the size, we see the error on all servers, but increasing the size only has an error on the 2016 server.

Comment: Could you check whether there are any STATISTICS other than [FS_FIELDLABEL_PK] that are auto created on your 2016 server, and try to drop them before the ALTER statement?

Comment: I don't think there are any statistics, or any that are relevant, because once I drop the primary key, and any indexes that happen to exist, then I can alter the column just fine.

I just don't understand why the 2017 Server doesn't care about there being indexes or primary keys present.

Comment: in the end, I can NOT reproduce the same issue so I coulndn't tell more.